# Url is loading in WebView Android

Tags: android-webview

I have a webview and i am trying to load url in this view now when i run this activity its giving warnigs and after sometime its crahing.

```
09-05 15:47:34.277: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:47:34.277: D/TilesManager(9057): new EGLContext from framework: 5c7252f0 
09-05 15:47:34.277: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:47:34.277: D/GLWebViewState(9057): Reinit shader
09-05 15:47:34.284: D/GLWebViewState(9057): Reinit transferQueue
09-05 15:48:01.800: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:48:01.800: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:48:21.613: I/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 15:48:21.652: I/dalvikvm(9057): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 15:48:29.855: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:48:29.863: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:48:57.409: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:48:57.417: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:49:24.933: I/Choreographer(9057): Skipped 1623 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:49:24.933: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:49:24.941: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:49:53.542: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:49:53.542: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:50:22.183: I/Choreographer(9057): Skipped 1688 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:50:22.183: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:50:22.183: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:50:49.558: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:50:49.558: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:51:18.628: I/Choreographer(9057): Skipped 1714 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:51:18.636: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:51:18.636: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:51:47.769: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:51:47.769: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:52:16.777: I/Choreographer(9057): Skipped 1711 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:52:16.784: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:52:16.784: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:52:46.909: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:52:46.909: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:53:15.550: I/Choreographer(9057): Skipped 1688 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 15:53:15.550: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted before update: 2.000000e-02
09-05 15:53:15.550: W/GLWebViewState(9057): WARNING, scale seems corrupted after update: 2.000000e-02

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView_links"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           />



</LinearLayout>


mWebView  = new WebView(this);



mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_links);


PIC_WIDTH= mWebView.getRight()-mWebView.getLeft();
mWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
mWebView.setInitialScale(2);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);



mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(mCurrentUrl != null && url != null && url.equals(mCurrentUrl)) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        view.loadUrl(url);
        mCurrentUrl = url;



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //heading.setText(view.getTitle());

    }
});

Log.i("----------------------------------",""+extras.getString("link_address"));

mWebView .loadUrl("http://www.alinadental.com/");
```